# Pass PHP Array to Google Maps Markers (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps

I'm storing my data to a php array and trying to pass it to javascript to get google maps display all the points in the php array. bellow is the php code (simplified and the javascript code for google maps.

-----PHP CODE--------

```
foreach(json_decode($response)->data as $item){ 
$name= $item->user->name;
   $latitude = $item->latitude;
   $longitude = $item->longitude;
$Array[$count] = array('name'=>$name,'lat'=>$latitude, 'long'=>$longitude, 'rgb'=>$count);
$js_array = json_encode($Array);
$count++;}
```

-----javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
 var locations = <?php echo $js_array;?>;    
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

**UPDATED JAVASCRIPT**

```
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($js_array);?>;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude;?>, <?php echo $longitude;?>),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
console.log(locations[i].lat);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].long),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i].name);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: only json_encode the final array after the loop. WHat part isn't working or what specific problems are you having?

Comment: the map displays but none of the markers are showing up

Comment: first look in console, likely having errors thrown. You aren't referencing the properties for lat/lng  ie `locations[i].lat` and `locations[i].long`

Comment: theirs no errors in the console

Comment: ok, well you still need to reference the named properties of the object. Since javascript doesn't have associative arrays your main array will be an array of objects

Comment: Sorry, Im kinda confused on what you said so this line is wrong.  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),

Comment: like this? position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].long),

Comment: should work, check by using `console.log(locations[i].lat);` to be certain

Comment: when i insert console.log(locations[i].lat); i get this error SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Comment: depends where you are inserting it

Comment: nvm I fixed the syntax error... but it doesnt show the values in the console

Comment: hard to help without seeing code. Log `locations[i]` inside the loop and inspect it then

Comment: console wont display anyting even console.log("test"); wont work

Comment: added new javascript code to the top

Comment: So i found out its never going into the for loop locations.length is undefined

Comment: well I assumed you had already looked at final source output and gotten past that point long ago. Good luck. Am at the point I can't do much more on this

Comment: Thanks for your help charlietfl! I got it working!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

In your updated javascript, you need to remove json_encode (already present in PHP). You were doing it twice.